# Expression expected & ':' expected

Tags: typescript, jwt, middleware, typeorm, routing-controllers

I'm trying to figure out why this code:

```
const extractJWT = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    logging.info(NAMESPACE, "Validating Token");

    let token = req.headers.authorization?.split(" ")[1];

    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, config.server.token.secret, (error, decoded) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    message: error.message,
                    error,
                });
            } else {
                res.locals.jwt = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: "Unauthorized",
        });
    }
};

export default extractJWT;
```

is throwing this error:

```
    TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
src/middleware/extractJWT.ts (11,43): Expression expected. (1109)
src/middleware/extractJWT.ts (11,57): ':' expected. (1005)
```

I'm trying to run extractJwt function as middleware on a Controller. I'm using [routing-controller](https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers) @UseBefore decorator on the action. Without the decorator, I don't get the error. With it, I do. I have no clue how it suddenly changes. I'd appreciate the any help here.

```
 @Get("/validate")
 @UseBefore(extractJWT)
async validate(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    logging.info(NAMESPACE, "Token Validated");
    return res.status(200).json({
        message: "Authorized",
    });
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this in the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), can you make sure your code is a [mcve]?

Comment: I was worried that it wouldn't be reproducible after I posted. I made an edit a minute ago trying to narrow it down a bit. I don't know how helpful it will be, but I only get this error when I try to pass the function while using routing-controllers @UseBefore() decorator.

Comment: Probably your configuration has a `object-literal-shorthand` rule, and you should use "fully described" object ```{ message: error.message, error: error }```

Comment: @ArtOlshansky Would you mind clarifying a bit. I have no idea what you mean. Sorry.

Comment: @codestomping I'm about line 11 in your example: here you have a "self assigned" object property `error`, but if your projects configuration has `object-literal-shorthand` rule you need change this line to `error: error`. I hope it's bit clear now, if no – ping me again